# Apache Camel with Spring Boot 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I using Apache Camel with spring boot and when I want to send a file size 25MB I got error 413 Request Entity Too Large.
I tried set but I still don't work.

```
spring.servlet:
  multipart:
    max-file-size: 50MB
    max-request-size: 50MB
```

I using camel-spring-boot 2.23.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to add this to restConfiguration()

```
restConfiguration()
    .componentProperty("chunkedMaxContentLength", String.valueOf(50 * 1024 * 1024))
    .endpointProperty("chunkedMaxContentLength", String.valueOf(50 * 1024 * 1024))
    .consumerProperty("chunkedMaxContentLength", String.valueOf(50 * 1024 * 1024))
```